# My Font Awesome Arrows are not rotating. Am I missing anything

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have simple bootstrap panels. My font awesome arrows are not rotating when aria-expanded is true. So I am missing anything.

Tried checking in console and when i looked into viewsource. I dont see aria-expanded attribute setting to it

I am using bootstrap 3.0 and font awesome.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <!-- First Panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading heading-background">
                    <h4 class="panel-title" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
                        Provider Summary
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Provider Summary</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Second Panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading heading-background">
                    <h4 class="panel-title" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
                        Services Offered
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Services Offered</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Third Panel -->
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading heading-background">
                    <h4 class="panel-title" style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree">
                        Other Linked Providers
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Other Linked Providers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p>Message From Scott</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
<style type="text/css">

/*Start - About*/

.panel-title {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

.heading-background {
    background-color: rgba(45,175,220,0.8) !important; /* Sample Blue 2*/
}

.panel-title::after {
    content: "\f107";
    color: #333;
    top: -2px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";

}

.panel-title[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
    content: "\f106";
}

/*Panel Heading Start*/
.home-heading {
    background-color: rgba(45,175,220,0.8) !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Cambria;
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
}
/*Panel Heading End*/

</style>
```

May be i missing something

Answer (score 0):

```css
.panel-title {
  position: relative;
}

.panel-title a::after {
  content: "\f105";
  color: #333;
  top: -2px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.panel-title a[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: "\f107";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true">Collapsible Group 1</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```